# Export processed text in a csv file in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have the following piece of code:

```
csv_file = 'similarweb/domains.csv'
file_in = open(csv_file, 'r')
file_out = open(csv_file, 'w')

with file_in as csv_read_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_read_file)
    for i, line in enumerate(reader):
        url = ', '.join(str(e) for e in line)
        final_result = url + " " + (content_client.category(url)['Category'])
        print final_result
```

**file_in.csv**:

word1
word2
...
word_n

**file_out.csv** - this is how `print final_result` looks like.

word1  explanation1
word2  explanation2
word_n explanation_n

This successfully takes as an input some rows from a csv file and add some information to each row. How can I export `final_result` in `file_out` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
csv_file = 'similarweb/domains.csv'

final_result = ""
with open(csv_file, 'r') as csv_read_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_read_file)
    for i, line in enumerate(reader):
        url = ', '.join(str(e) for e in line)
        final_result += url + " " + (content_client.category(url)['Category']) + "\n"

with open(csv_file, 'w') as csv_write_file:
    csv_write_file.write(final_result)
```

Comment: This isn't what I wanted. I want `final_result` to be exported in a new csv file (`file_out`)

Comment: In your question, you have the line `file_out = open(csv_file, 'w')`, that's why I thought you wanted to overwrite the original file. Can you see how you could modify my code to change the file name of the output file?

Comment: I succeeded but it only exports the last line of `final_result`

Comment: did you copy my example exactly? In particular do you have `final_result +=` ?

Comment: Missed `final_result = ""`. Thank you

Comment: could you also tell me how would I put a `tab` delimiter between, `word1` and `explanation1` , `word2` and `explanation2` and so on ?

Comment: sure, just change `url + " "` to `url + "\t"`